# Change the color of the tabview on the actionBar

Tags: android-actionbar

I am new to Android Development.
Initially tabView on the actionBar contains blue color if it has the focus. I want to change only that to another color. So the other style components of the actionBar should remain same.

I wrote the following code:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_tabdesign</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And in manifest I wrote this

```
<activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".mainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActivityTheme"
>
</activity>
```

When I run my app, the action bar completely disappears! 
I could really use some help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to change the background of the tabs, set the color to a selector in drawable and define the different states (pressed/non-pressed) - (focus/no focus).

This post has more details on resolving this problem:
[ActionBar change color/drawable of selected tab only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954567/actionbar-change-color-drawable-of-selected-tab-only)

Hope this helps.