# ActionBar change color/drawable of selected tab only?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

To change the color or background of **all** `ACtionBar` tabs, I can use `actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable()`.

But how can I change the color or drawable of selected tab? For example, the background color of tabs is black, but when I select some tab, I want it to be red.

Possible to do this as I haven't been able to find topics on this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the Selector being used for tabs:

```
<style name="Custom" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/Widget.Custom.TabView</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/Widget.Custom.TabView</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Custom.TabView" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/your_custom_selector</item>
</style>
```

Check out the Drawable in ABS titled `abs__tab_indicator_ab_holo.xml` for reference on how to create `your_custom_selector`.

You want to change anything that has `android:state_selected="true"`.